# Python Cherrypy: Disable logging of requests

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm trying to silence the logging of http requests from CherryPy. I've tried

```
cherrypy.log.access_file = None
```

which as I understand it should remove the handler for access logging, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silencing cherrypy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167884/silencing-cherrypy)

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, telling CherryPy to stop logging doesn't actually do anything when you've independently configured Python's `logging` module.  The solution is to do this:

```
cherrypy.log.error_log.propagate = False
cherrypy.log.access_log.propagate = False
```

(Hat tip to [this blog post](http://blog.fealdia.org/2011/04/19/how-to-prevent-cherrypy-from-logging-after-logging-basicconfig/), which is unfortunately now down.)

Answer (score 5):

This is how I normally do:

```
    access_log = cherrypy.log.access_log
    for handler in tuple(access_log.handlers):
        access_log.removeHandler(handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

It says on the [docs page](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/_cplogging.html#custom-handlers) for the latest version of CherryPy to set the handler to `""` not to `None`

```
# Remove the default FileHandlers if present.
log.error_file = ""
log.access_file = ""
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work either. On the same page you linked to, in the classes section it says that access_file can be set to either None or ''. But neither seem to work for me. Though I can turn off logging all together by setting log.screen to false.